# Weak pointer for the array of delegates in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I'm new to iOS programming in Objective-C. I know that i should declare pointers to delegates using weak attribute. What about NSMutableArray of delegates? i need to have a list of delegates:

```
@protocol IHandler <NSObject>

- (void)addDelegate: (id<IDelegate>) delegate;
- (void)removeDelegate: (id<IDelegate>) delegate;
- (BOOL)hasDelegate: (id<IDelegate>) delegate;
- (void)clearDelegates;

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically you should be talking about observers, not delegates, in a one-to-many relationship. Nitpicking aside, you should use the semi-recent [`NSPointerArray`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSPointerArray_Class/Introduction/Introduction.html), specifically a `+weakObjectsPointerArray`. Available since iOS 6, it's an array of pointers that, unlike `NSArray`, may contain `NULL` and can automatically keep only a weak relationship to individual entries.

Comment: so i should leave `(id<IDelegate>) delegate` in interface for type-safety but use NSPointerArray in the .m. Should i compare to nil when walking through items of NSPointerArray?

Comment: what is preferred `NSPointerArray` or `NSMutableSet` created by CFSetCreateMutable(NULL, 0, NULL)? why? (http://a-coding.com/observer-pattern-in-objective-c/)

Comment: `NSPoniterArray` would be preferable — that kind of set (or the equivalent `CFArray`) would host unsafe_unretained pointers rather than weak references. And, yes, you'd probably want to keep the interface you've designed so as to communicate that the protocol is necessary, both to humans and for the compiler to check for warnings.